# GWT uibinder ,taking too much time for autosuggestion

Tags: gwt, gxt, uibinder

We are using GXT with GWT(2.4) in our project. We are using UIBinder for page design. Currently we are facing too much problem to write code in xml page. It is taking too much time to auto suggest (become non responsive  when we press ctl+Space for autosuggestion). Don't understand what is the problem.

Help needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by a slow internet connection or remote server, which makes retrieving the XSD files slow. You can add the XSD to your catalog, refering to a local file instead of a remote URL :

```
Location:        http://dl.google.com/gwt/dtd/com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.xsd
URI:           http://dl.google.com/gwt/dtd/com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.xsd
Key Type:        Namespace Name
Key:                urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui


Location:        http://dl.google.com/gwt/dtd/uibinder.xsd
URI:           http://dl.google.com/gwt/dtd/uibinder.xsd
Key Type:        Namespace Name
Key:                urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder
```

In Eclipse >> Preferences >> XML >> Catalog

In User part you can add your custom catalog, download the XSD files mentionned, and point to the local version of the XSD files.